# Django: exporting excel files in my memory

Tags: python, django

I want to export some Excel file in my memory, and here is my code.

```
wrapper = open('/home/filename.xlsx')
response = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment ; filename=%s' % smart_str('filename.xlsx')
response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str('/home/filename.xlsx')
        return response
```

There is no problem when i use Python 2.7 but if i use Python 3.5 it occurs error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 10:invalid start byte
```

I guess the error is because of their difference (open function)

What is the appropriate way to open excel file in my memory and export it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x files are opened in text mode by default. Change your first line to:

```
wrapper = open('/home/filename.xlsx', 'rb')
```

From [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) (emphasis mine):

> Normally, files are opened in text mode, that means, you read and write strings from and to the file, which are encoded in a specific encoding. If encoding is not specified, the default is platform dependent (see open()). 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects. **This mode should be used for all files that don’t contain text.**